# Linear Model + tolerance intervals: How to show that when a condition is fulfilled for a tool it is also fulfilled for another related tool?

Tags: inference, linear-model, quality-control, equivalence, tolerance-interval

**The problem**

Imagine that you have two different tools that produce data at given time points $t_1,...,t_m$. Suppose that we only have access to the mean and standard deviation of the data at each time points for each tool. Let us write it like this:

- means of tool 1: $T_1(t_1),...,T_1(t_m)$ and the standard deviation $S_1(t_1),...,S_1(t_m)$,
- means of tool 2: $T_2(t_1),...,T_2(t_m)$ and the standard deviation $S_2(t_1),...,S_2(t_m)$.

For each time points, we also have a 95% 99% lower tolerance bound (based on normality) calculated for each tool:

- Bounds for tool 1: $L_1(t_1),...,L_1(t_m)$ with $L_1(t_i) = T_1(t_i) - kS_1(t_i)$ where $k$ is parameter that depends on the sample size and the overage of the tolerance interval,
- Bounds for tool 2: $L_2(t_1),...,L_2(t_m)$.

The goal is to show that, in the future, if $L_1$ is greater than a given limit $M$ then $L_2$ is greater too. Or, if the percentage of data that are greater than $M$ is at least 99% for tool 1 then this same probability is also at least bigger than 99% for tool 2.

**What I have done**

With the linear model
$$    T_j(t) =  \alpha_0 + \alpha_1 t + \beta \cdot \mathcal{I}[tool == tool \ j ] + \gamma t \cdot\mathcal{I}[tool == tool \ j ],$$

we can determine if the two means have the same evolution through the time, where $\mathcal{I}[tool == tool \ j ]$ equal $1$ when the tool used is the $tool\ j$ and $0$ otherwise.

I found out that the slopes are equal but not the intercept. tool 2 is shifted of a amount $\Delta$ below tool 1.

To claim that tool 2 fulfills the condition when tool 1 does, I have just imposed that the following is verified:

$$
\Delta < \min_{t_1,...,t_n}L_2(t) - \min_{t_1,...,t_n}L_1(t).
$$

**The question**
I do not know if it is sufficient to show the condition. Do you have any critics or comment about this method? I would love to discuss about it and highlight the main issues.